# How to use RegEx using Python?

Tags: python, regex, python-2.7

I want to extract some data from a file. File contains this data
config.txt -->

```
Link-local IPv6 Address . . . . . : fe80::b84b:8729:c16b:8d16%1
IPv4 Address. . . . . . . . . . . : 10.132.83.151
Subnet Mask . . . . . . . . . . . : 255.255.254.0
Default Gateway . . . . . . . . . : 10.132.78.1
```

Code:

```
f = open('config')
for line in f:
    # what should be logic to grab data like
```

Output should be:

```
fe80::b84b:8729:c16b:8d16%1
10.132.83.151
255.255.254.0
10.132.78.1
```

Comment: Stack Overflow is not a code writing forum. What have you tried so far? Please show your work.

Comment: In your first output line you seem to be adding random spaces - what's the logic behind that?

Comment: Nicely formed question, but SO isn't code writing tool. See more there http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/17494/im-new-to-stackoverflow-what-should-i-consider-before-asking-questions

Answer (score -2):

how about this?

```
for line in f:
    print(line.split(':',1)[1].strip())
```

Comment: Nice answer of how skip rexexps. I want to upvote, but cannot. See Soviut comment on question, not sure it deserve your answer ...

Comment: Thanks Daz, but this solution is using string not using regex. i wanna solve with regex.

Answer (score -2):

Option 1:

```
# pick everything after a fixed number of characters
grab_after = len('Link-local IPv6 Address . . . . . : ')
f = open('config')
for line in f:
    print(line[grab_after:])
```

Option 2:

```
# pick everything after last space
f = open('config')
for line in f:
    print(line.split()[-1])
```

Comment: Great options,  I want to upvote, but cannot. See Soviut comment on question, not sure it deserve your answer ...

Comment: thanks, but i wanna solve it using regex not through string operations.